# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targetsというエラーの対処法を教えていただきたいです。

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy, 深層学習, keras

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import models

    def homework(train_X, train_y, test_X):
    # WRITE ME!
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
    model.add((Dropout(0.5)))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add((Dropout(0.5)))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))


    model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_X, train_y,epochs=20, batch_size=1000, verbose=1)

    y_test_predict = model.predict(test_X)
    y_test_predict = np.argmax(y_test_predict, axis=1)



    return y_test_predictimport numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def load_mnist():
    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='.')
    mnist_X, mnist_y = shuffle(mnist.data.astype('float32'),
                               mnist.target.astype('int32'), random_state=42)

    mnist_X = mnist_X / 255.0
    mnist_y = to_categorical(mnist_y,10)


    return train_test_split(mnist_X, mnist_y,
                test_size=0.2,
                random_state=42)

def validate_homework():
    n_data = 10000
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = load_mnist()

    # validate for small dataset
    train_X_mini = train_X[:n_data]
    train_y_mini = train_y[:n_data]
    test_X_mini = test_X[:n_data]
    test_y_mini = test_y[:n_data]

    pred_y = homework(train_X_mini, train_y_mini, test_X_mini)
    print('f1_score' + f1_score(test_y_mini, pred_y, average='macro'))
```

上記のようなコードでMNISTをニューラルネットワークで実装しようとしています。validate_homeworkを実行すると、

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets
```

というエラーが表示されます。どなたか解決法を教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: mnistからloadした時点でのデータ構造がどうなっているのかよく覚えてないのであまり自信ないですが，loadしてすぐにmnist_xとmnist_yをreshapeしたほうがいいのではないでしょうか？この辺がわかりやすいかと思います．-> 
 https://qiita.com/ash8h/items/29e24fc617b832fba136

Comment: 試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

Comment: to_categorical を使わず、cross-entropyをsparse-cross-entropyにするとうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。